# Frame won't empty and repaint with an if statement

Tags: java

I have an if statement that check for a true or false, enterGame, which will add things to a JFrame, there is a button that will change the Boolean too true and try to replace things in the JFrame once its been emptied. It doesn't repaint my Frame once I remove everything from it. Crystal is my teacher and we're both stumped.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUIDemo implements ActionListener
{
int mapX, mapY;

private JFrame mainFrame;
private JLabel headerLabel;
private JLabel statusLabel;
private JPanel controlPanel;
private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel logonPanel = new JPanel();
private JLabel msglabel;
private JButton logButton;
boolean enterGame = false;
JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Username:", JLabel.CENTER);
JLabel passLabel = new JLabel("Password:", JLabel.CENTER);

JLabel[][] maplabels = new JLabel[3][3];

public String[][] placeNames = { {"Forest", "Desert", "Jungle"}, 
{"Ice Cave", "Village", "Wizard's Tower"}, 
{"Lake", "Moutain", "Ocean"}};

public GUIDemo()
{
prepareGUI();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
GUIDemo swingDemo = new GUIDemo(); 
swingDemo.showDemo(); 
}

private void prepareGUI()
{
mainFrame = new JFrame("Swing Demo");
mainFrame.setSize(350,200);
mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
logonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

//mainFrame.setLayout(null);

headerLabel = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER );
statusLabel = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER); 

mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() 
{
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent)
{
System.exit(0);
} 
}); 
controlPanel = new JPanel();
controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

mainFrame.add(logonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
//mainFrame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
//mainFrame.add(statusLabel);
mainPanel.setVisible(false); 
logonPanel.setVisible(true); 

mainFrame.setVisible(true); 

}

private void showDemo()
{ 
if (enterGame == true)
{
//logonPanel.setVisible(false); 

//mainFrame.setVisible(false); 
mainFrame.remove(logonPanel);
mainFrame.validate();
mainFrame.repaint();
//mainFrame.removeAll();
headerLabel.setText("Location: " + placeNames[mapX][mapY]);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
panel.setSize(300,300);
panel2.setSize(300,300);
GridLayout compassLayout = new GridLayout(3,3);

JButton button1 = new JButton("");
JButton button2 = new JButton("North");
JButton button3 = new JButton("");
JButton button4 = new JButton("West");
JButton button5 = new JButton("");
JButton button6 = new JButton("East");
JButton button7 = new JButton("");
JButton button8 = new JButton("South");
JButton button9 = new JButton("");
button1.setVisible (false);
button2.addActionListener(this);
button3.setVisible (false);
button4.addActionListener(this);
button5.setVisible (false);
button6.addActionListener(this);
button7.setVisible (false);
button8.addActionListener(this);
button9.setVisible (false);


GridLayout MapLayout = new GridLayout(3,3);

maplabels[0][0] = new JLabel("F", JLabel.CENTER);
maplabels[0][1] = new JLabel("D", JLabel.CENTER);
maplabels[0][2] = new JLabel("J", JLabel.CENTER);
maplabels[1][0] = new JLabel("I", JLabel.CENTER);
maplabels[1][1] = new JLabel("V", JLabel.CENTER);
maplabels[1][2] = new JLabel("W", JLabel.CENTER);
maplabels[2][0] = new JLabel("L", JLabel.CENTER);
maplabels[2][1] = new JLabel("M", JLabel.CENTER);
maplabels[2][2] = new JLabel("O", JLabel.CENTER);

panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
panel.setLayout(compassLayout); 
panel.add(button1);
panel.add(button2); 
panel.add(button3); 
panel.add(button4); 
panel.add(button5); 
panel.add(button6); 
panel.add(button7); 
panel.add(button8); 
panel.add(button9); 

panel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
panel2.setLayout(MapLayout); 
panel2.add(maplabels[0][0]);
panel2.add(maplabels[0][1]); 
panel2.add(maplabels[0][2]); 
panel2.add(maplabels[1][0]); 
panel2.add(maplabels[1][1]); 
panel2.add(maplabels[1][2]); 
panel2.add(maplabels[2][0]); 
panel2.add(maplabels[2][1]); 
panel2.add(maplabels[2][2]); 

mainPanel.add(headerLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
mainPanel.add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
mainPanel.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
mainFrame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
else
{
//mainFrame.removeAll();
BorderLayout borderUser = new BorderLayout();
BorderLayout borderPass = new BorderLayout();
JPanel userPanel = new JPanel(borderUser);
JPanel passPanel = new JPanel(borderPass);
logButton = new JButton("Log On");
logButton.addActionListener(this);


JTextField userField = new JTextField();
JTextField passField = new JTextField();

userPanel.add(userLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
userPanel.add(userField, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

passPanel.add(passLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
passPanel.add(passField, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

logonPanel.add(userPanel);
logonPanel.add(passPanel);
logonPanel.add(new JPanel());
logonPanel.add(logButton); 
}

mainFrame.validate();
mainFrame.repaint();
mainFrame.setVisible(true); 
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
String buttonName = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getText(); 
//userLabel.setText(buttonName);

if(buttonName == "Log On")
{
//userLabel.setText("HI");
enterGame = true;
this.showDemo(); 

}
else
{
maplabels[mapX][mapY].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());

if(buttonName == "North")
{
mapX = (3 + mapX - 1)% 3;
}
if(buttonName == "South")
{
mapX = (3 + mapX + 1)% 3;
}
if(buttonName == "West")
{
mapY = (3 + mapY - 1)% 3;
}
if(buttonName == "East")
{
mapY = (3 + mapY + 1)% 3;
} 

maplabels[mapX][mapY].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
headerLabel.setText("Location: " + placeNames[mapX][mapY]);
} 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code. First, you are comparing string with double equals sign i.e (==). This will never do your job. In java, if the thing you are comparing is not primitive type (which String is not) then it will do the reference comparison. Thus your comparison buttonName == *something* will never return true.

Second, you get blank window after logging in because you have not set the visibility of your mainPanel to true. Below is the corrected code that works:

```
public class GUIDemo implements ActionListener
{
    int mapX, mapY;

    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JLabel headerLabel;
    private JLabel statusLabel;
    private JPanel controlPanel;
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel logonPanel = new JPanel();
    private JLabel msglabel;
    private JButton logButton;
    boolean enterGame = false;
    JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Username:", JLabel.CENTER);
    JLabel passLabel = new JLabel("Password:", JLabel.CENTER);

    JLabel[][] maplabels = new JLabel[3][3];

    public String[][] placeNames = { {"Forest", "Desert", "Jungle"}, 
                                     {"Ice Cave", "Village", "Wizard's Tower"}, 
                                     {"Lake", "Moutain", "Ocean"}};

    public GUIDemo()
    {
        prepareGUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GUIDemo swingDemo = new GUIDemo(); 
        swingDemo.showDemo(); 
    }

    private void prepareGUI()
    {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Swing Demo");
        mainFrame.setSize(350,200);
        mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        logonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

        //mainFrame.setLayout(null);

        headerLabel = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER );
        statusLabel = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER); 

        mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() 
        {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent)
        {
        System.exit(0);
        } 
        }); 
        controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        mainFrame.add(logonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //mainFrame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //mainFrame.add(statusLabel);
        mainPanel.setVisible(false); 
        logonPanel.setVisible(true); 

        mainFrame.setVisible(true); 

    }

    private void showDemo()
    { 
        if (enterGame == true)
        {

            //logonPanel.setVisible(false); 

            //mainFrame.setVisible(false); 
            mainFrame.remove(logonPanel);
            mainFrame.revalidate();
            mainFrame.repaint();
            //mainFrame.removeAll();
            headerLabel.setText("Location: " + placeNames[mapX][mapY]);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
            panel.setSize(300,300);
            panel2.setSize(300,300);
            GridLayout compassLayout = new GridLayout(3,3);

            JButton button1 = new JButton("");
            JButton button2 = new JButton("North");
            JButton button3 = new JButton("");
            JButton button4 = new JButton("West");
            JButton button5 = new JButton("");
            JButton button6 = new JButton("East");
            JButton button7 = new JButton("");
            JButton button8 = new JButton("South");
            JButton button9 = new JButton("");
            button1.setVisible (false);
            button2.addActionListener(this);
            button3.setVisible (false);
            button4.addActionListener(this);
            button5.setVisible (false);
            button6.addActionListener(this);
            button7.setVisible (false);
            button8.addActionListener(this);
            button9.setVisible (false);


            GridLayout MapLayout = new GridLayout(3,3);

            maplabels[0][0] = new JLabel("F", JLabel.CENTER);
            maplabels[0][1] = new JLabel("D", JLabel.CENTER);
            maplabels[0][2] = new JLabel("J", JLabel.CENTER);
            maplabels[1][0] = new JLabel("I", JLabel.CENTER);
            maplabels[1][1] = new JLabel("V", JLabel.CENTER);
            maplabels[1][2] = new JLabel("W", JLabel.CENTER);
            maplabels[2][0] = new JLabel("L", JLabel.CENTER);
            maplabels[2][1] = new JLabel("M", JLabel.CENTER);
            maplabels[2][2] = new JLabel("O", JLabel.CENTER);

            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
            panel.setLayout(compassLayout); 
            panel.add(button1);
            panel.add(button2); 
            panel.add(button3); 
            panel.add(button4); 
            panel.add(button5); 
            panel.add(button6); 
            panel.add(button7); 
            panel.add(button8); 
            panel.add(button9); 

            panel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
            panel2.setLayout(MapLayout); 
            panel2.add(maplabels[0][0]);
            panel2.add(maplabels[0][1]); 
            panel2.add(maplabels[0][2]); 
            panel2.add(maplabels[1][0]); 
            panel2.add(maplabels[1][1]); 
            panel2.add(maplabels[1][2]); 
            panel2.add(maplabels[2][0]); 
            panel2.add(maplabels[2][1]); 
            panel2.add(maplabels[2][2]); 

            mainPanel.add(headerLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            mainPanel.add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
            mainPanel.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            mainFrame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            mainPanel.setVisible(true);

        }
        else
        {
            //mainFrame.removeAll();
            BorderLayout borderUser = new BorderLayout();
            BorderLayout borderPass = new BorderLayout();
            JPanel userPanel = new JPanel(borderUser);
            JPanel passPanel = new JPanel(borderPass);
            logButton = new JButton("Log On");
            logButton.addActionListener(this);


            JTextField userField = new JTextField();
            JTextField passField = new JTextField();

            userPanel.add(userLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            userPanel.add(userField, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

            passPanel.add(passLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            passPanel.add(passField, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

            logonPanel.add(userPanel);
            logonPanel.add(passPanel);
            logonPanel.add(new JPanel());
            logonPanel.add(logButton); 
        }

        //mainFrame.getContentPane().validate();
        //mainFrame.getContentPane().repaint();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true); 
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        String buttonName = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getText(); 


        if(buttonName.equals("Log On"))
        {

            this.enterGame = true;
            this.showDemo(); 

        }
        else
        {
            maplabels[mapX][mapY].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());

            if(buttonName.equals("North"))
            {
                mapX = (3 + mapX - 1)% 3;
            }
            if(buttonName.equals("South"))
            {
                mapX = (3 + mapX + 1)% 3;
            }
            if(buttonName.equals("West"))
            {
                mapY = (3 + mapY - 1)% 3;
            }
            if(buttonName.equals("East"))
            {
                mapY = (3 + mapY + 1)% 3;
            } 

            maplabels[mapX][mapY].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
            headerLabel.setText("Location: " + placeNames[mapX][mapY]);
        } 
    }
}
```